# Insert into, select and where statement combined

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

How to insert record from Table A to Table B based on the conditions in Table C.

Table A:

```
ID  Name   DateFrom   DateTo
1   Alex   22-7-2015  26-7-2015
2   Alice  21-8-2015  25-8-2015
```

Table C:

```
ID  Quarter   DateFrom   DateTo
1   Quater 1  1-7-2015  31-7-2015
2   Quater 2  1-8-2015  31-8-2015
```

If the records from Table A is between the date range in Table C. It will insert into a new Table B.

Redemption is Table B

```
insert into redemption(staffID,staffName,department,pointsAccumulated,referrerID) 
select referrerStaffID,referrerName,referrerDepartment,SUM(points),activeDirectoryID 
FROM referral 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from redemption1 where referrerID=activeDirectoryID) group by activeDirectoryID;
```

Comment: Can you please share the structure of table b and the records you want inserted for this sample data? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Insert into tableB(Id,name,datefrom,dateto)
select t1.Id,t1.name,t1.datefrom,t1.dateto from tableA as t1 
inner join tableC as t2 on t1.id=t2.id 
where 
t1.datefrom between t2.datefrom and t2.dateto or 
t1.dateto between t2.datefrom and t2.dateto
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a correlated subquery with `WHERE NOT EXISTS..` construct

```
insert into 
redemption(
            staffID,
            staffName,
            department,
            pointsAccumulated,
            referrerID
          ) 
select 
referrerStaffID,
referrerName,
referrerDepartment,
SUM(points),
activeDirectoryID 
FROM referral  r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                    select 1 from redemption1 r1 where 
                    r1.referrerID=r1.activeDirectoryID 
                    and (r.datefrom between r1.datefrom and r1.dateto or 
                         r.dateto between r1.datefrom and r1.dateto) 
                 )
group by r.referrerStaffID,r.referrerName,r.referrerDepartment,r.activeDirectoryID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query

```
insert into tableB(id,name,datefrom,dateto)
select A.id,A.name,A.datefrom,A.dateto from tableA A join tableC C 
                       on A.id=C.id 
      where TO_DATE(A.datefrom,'DD-mm-yyyy') 
            between TO_DATE(C.datefrom,'DD-mm-yyyy') and TO_DATE(c.dateto,'DD-mm-yyyy')
      and TO_DATE(A.dateto,'DD-mm-yyyy') 
            between TO_DATE(C.datefrom,'DD-mm-yyyy') and TO_DATE(c.dateto,'DD-mm-yyyy')
```

Please check the answer here [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/112f1/8)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is already answered by everyone else, but I'd just like to add if the schema for table A and table B are the same you can also do something like:

```
Insert into tableB 
Select * from tableA
Where....
```

Not repeating where clause since its already answered.